# Stop AltGr From Triggering Menu Bar Items?

Tags: javafx

## Introduction

The first `MenuItem` inside my `MenuBar` receives focus whenever I press down my [AltGr key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key). This is by no means a wanted behavior—although it appears as though it’s the default behavior offered by the `MenuBar` itself.

This gets slightly annoying since I’m on a [Swedish keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY#Swedish)—meaning both the `[]` and the `{}` are called upon using the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key.

### Problem

I’d like to remove the functionality whereas the first `MenuItem` inside the `MenuBar` gets activated upon pressing down <kbd>AltGr</kbd> on a keyboard.

### Research

As usual I’ve been browsing around *Stackoverflow* in the hope to find an answer—but in vain. It’s honestly not very surprising that no one has had this problem before due to the majority of *Stackoverflow* not actually using Swedish keyboard layouts.

### Moreover

Perhaps someone has either seen a post like this somewhere—in that case, do mark this as a duplicate—in any other case, either point me and anyone who might come across this question in the right direction, or simply answer this question with a somewhat shallow example.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at MenuBarSkin's constructor, it adds a scene event key handler which focuses the menu if any keypress involving Alt is not consumed by the time it reaches the scene:

```
        // put focus on the first menu when the alt key is pressed
        scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
            if (e.isAltDown()  && !e.isConsumed()) {
                firstMenuRunnable.run();
            }
        });
```

I've worked around this by putting an event handler on the main content pane of my window, that looks for the key-pressed event of ALT_GRAPH and consumes it.  Since my handler goes before the scene handler, it should prevent the menu-focus behaviour from triggering.  Roughly:

```
tabPane.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {

        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ALT_GRAPH)
        {
            e.consume();
            return;
        }
});
```

I'm not sure if AltGr always shows up as ALT_GRAPH; I believe I have seen it show up as ALT with e.isControlDown() being true, but you could also consume that event if none of your menu shortcuts involve Ctrl+Alt (which I'm guessing they won't, as they would be triggered by AltGr since it maps to Ctrl+Alt on Windows).

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem and based on above answer I was able to solve it by using below code:

```
mainAnchorPane.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
        if (e.isAltDown() || KeyCode.ALT_GRAPH == e.getCode()) {
            e.consume();
        }
    });
```

On my environment when I pressed AltGr then event reported that Ctrl and AltGr buttons were pressed in this exact order. I didn't care about Ctrl but Alt was anoying so I kill both of my Alts with above code.